# Exclude package in maven-war-plugin in classesClassifier

Tags: maven, maven-war-plugin

we *mavenize* an old application which was build with *ant*. It's an multimodule project.

They did some funny things with one web-module, a jar-module has a dependency on. This I can solve with some configuration in the *maven-war-plugin*:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <attachClasses>true</attachClasses>
        <classesClassifier>classes</classesClassifier>
        ...
```

With this I can refer to an jar without the web stuff:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
    <classifier>classes</classifier>
    <version>2.23.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

Now I found out that with the ant scripts they filtered most of the packages out, which I need to do so too with maven.

Is there a way to exclude packages just for the jar version which is built from the maven-war-plugin? The war need to be complete.

Thanks!

Comment: I assume the classes to exclude in the classes JAR, should still be present in the JAR inside the WAR? If so, I don't think this is possible no.

Comment: Please specify what packages to be removed and what do you mean *war need to be complete* and share the `pom.xml`s clearing out what depends on what.

Comment: In the resulting Jar we should exclude packages/classes but not in the War itself. I think @Tunaki is right, that's just not possible.

Comment: It would be better to have another module generating the JAR without those classes (keep the excluded one in the WAR) and have the WAR depend on it.